# Request validation/Data-integrity

Tags: validation, data-integrity

I have a problem where I have a service which takes a request (`R`) and then returns some `List` of **selectable objects** (`S1, S2, S3 ....`). The client is supposed to select one of the objects (set it in the request) and make a purchase call (`request = R + Si`). When the purchase call is made we need to verify that the object selected by client was indeed the one of the ones that we gave him. 
Is this a standard problem? What might be the most elegant way to solve this?

Some of the solutions I have thought of:

1) Recompute `S1, S2, S3` and then validate. We don't want to recompute as it is expensive.

2) Give out a token `T1, T2, T3` corresponding to each `S1, S1, S3` and then do the validation against that token. One of the ways of calculating the token:

=> Have a database where you have a token (`UUID`) stored against `S` and `checksum(R)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like crypto signing here. Django has it built-in, but I think the idea is pretty popular so you easy implement it in your language/environment or even find existing libraries.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signing/